# PhpStorm 2021.3.3 построение FlameGraph

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

Проект в docker с docker-compose

```
✗ docker -v
Docker version 20.10.23, build 7155243

✗ docker-compose -v
Docker Compose version v2.15.1\

 php -v
PHP 7.4.30 (cli) (built: Sep 13 2022 11:11:11) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader + ionCube24 v12.0.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2022, by ionCube Ltd.
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.30, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.8.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2019, by Derick Rethans
```

Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Xdebug настроен так docker/php/php.ini

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.idekey = "PHPSTORM"
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_mode = "req"
xdebug.remote_port = 9001
xdebug.remote_host = "host.docker.internal"

xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.output_dir=logs
```

xdebug работает - ентрипоинты видит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы построить FlameGraph нужно сохранить дамп профилирования - но такой кнопки в PhpStorm найти не могу. В папке logs тоже пусто

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

запускаю приложение с параметром `XDEBUG_PROFILE=1`

http://crm.local/index.php/interface/dashboard/index?XDEBUG_PROFILE=1